# When did challenging to a duel cease to be a practice in English culture?

Tags: england, cultural-history, social-history

In the [Aubrey Maturin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubrey%E2%80%93Maturin_series) series of novels, there are at least two scenes where the protagonists are challenged to a duel:

1. [Post-Captain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Captain_(novel)) - Aubrey and Maturin about Aubrey's reputation with the Admiralty
2. [HMS Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Surprise_(novel)) - Stephen challenges another lover of [Diana Villers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diana_Villiers) to a duel

Now these novels are set in the period of English History [1800-1815] and are [generally regarded](http://www.nytimes.com/library/books/010700obit-obrian.html) to be [meticulously researched](http://www.smh.com.au/articles/2003/11/28/1069825977816.html) [historical fiction](http://www.nytimes.com/books/98/10/18/specials/obrian-comesin.html).

It seems to me that challenging another man to a duel (apart from being illegal), is no longer a part of English culture.

My question is: **When did challenging to a duel cease to be a practice in English culture?**

Comment: It did? In that case I'd better go put my duelling gloves away and find some other way of avenging my honour...

Comment: There's a chapter on this in the excellent "Extraordinary popular delusions and the madness of crowds" - it was condemned in the 1600s by the Pope, made widely illegal, but took a very long time to stamp out.

Comment: I France the last duel to be held was in 1967 between two members of the National Assembly: Gaston Defferre, who won and René Ribière. I know it is not an answer to the question, and I would have prefered to put this in the comments but I need reputation points to do it.

Comment: I seem to remember a very similar question about the decline of duelling. Anyone know what I'm thinking of?

Comment: @Duncan I vaguely remember it too, though IIRC it wasn't restricted to England.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was about the last duel to take place. Anyway, similar themes were addressed, so if I find it I'll let you know @hawkeye

Answer (score 35, accepted):

During the 1830s and 1840s.

> In the twenties dueling was still common. From 1815 to 1830 Castlereagh, Canning, and Wellington were responsible in turn for the government of England, and they all fought duels. **In the thirties dueling died out under the pressure of public opinion**, and in 1844 the amended articles of war stated that any officer who fought a duel would be cashiered.
>
> **<sub>- Thomson, David, and P. A. Williams. *England in the Nineteenth Century, 1815-1914.* Vol. 8. Penguin books, 1950.</sub>**

The practice went into sharp decline and went virtually extinct after the mid 1840s or so. The last recorded fatal duel seemed to have happened in 1852, between two *Frenchmen*.

Comment: Wow - well referenced answer - right on the question.

Comment: Just after Jackson's death too...

Comment: Although hang around a bar and you'll still see guys fighting over a women. :)

Comment: This was a surprise for me, because in mainland Europe duels ceased to be a practice only around WW1.

Comment: Indeed, German college boys were basically required to duel each other regularly up until WW1.

Comment: @Avery That's a sporting duel with swords where the loser is very unlikely to be killed.

Answer (score 2):

In 1964 two Magdalen undergrads, Adam Poynter and Rory Donellan, fought a duel after Mr Donellan described a Lady Margaret girl whom Mr Poynter admired as "thick" and Mr Poynter slapped Mr Donellan with a glove.  Honour was satisfied when Mr Poynter sustained a cut in his wrist and the gentlemen went back to Mr Donellan's room for a whisky.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Sources to support your assertions would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: @sempaiscuba See https://www.nytimes.com/1964/02/20/archives/2-duel-to-a-wristnick-at-oxford-over-a-girl.html